# reading Excel data using getvalue in C++

Tags: c++, excel

I know that to read from Excel using C++ we can use GetItem() like in this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < nbRows; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < nbCols; j++)
  {
    input[i][j] = range_data->GetItem(i+1, j+1);
  }
}
```

but it will take time if the range size is big.

I know that to write in Excel we can use Value2 function and it is faster than writing using getItem(). To use Value2 function, we have to put the result into safearray before store it to Excel.
I have this code to write the result from C++ to Excel:

```
Excel::_WorksheetPtr sheet_XD = spXlBook->Worksheets->GetItem(L"XD");
VARIANT arrXD;
arrXD.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
{
   SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
   sab[0].lLbound = 1; 
   sab[0].cElements = nbRows;
   sab[1].lLbound = 1; 
   sab[1].cElements = nbCols;
   arrXD.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);
}

for(i = 0; i < nbRows; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < nbCols; j++) 
  {    
    VARIANT tmpXD;
    tmpXD.vt = VT_I4;
    tmpXD.lVal = 0;
    if (XD_best[i][j] > 0.5)
    tmpXD.lVal = 1;
    long indicesXD[] = {i+1, j+1};
    SafeArrayPutElement(arrXD.parray, indicesXD, (void *)&tmpXD);
  }
}
Excel::RangePtr range_XD = sheet_XD->GetRange(L"XD");
range_XD->Value2 = arrXD;
```

I think that we can do the opposite of writing code to use in reading data (using value2). I have tried using SafeArrayGetElement but unfortunately, I couldn't get the data from excel using getValue.

this is my code to read the data from Excel using value2:

```
HRESULT hr;
_variant_t tcvt = rngSh->GetValue2();

if (tcvt.vt == (VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT))
{
    SAFEARRAY * sa = tcvt.parray;
    long colMax;
    hr = ::SafeArrayGetUBound(sa, 1, &colMax);
    long colMin;
    hr = ::SafeArrayGetLBound(sa, 1, &colMin);
    cout << "colMax = " << colMax << endl;
    cout << "colMin = " << colMin << endl;

    long index[2];
    index[1] = 1;
    for (long colIdx = colMin; colIdx <= colMax; colIdx++)
    {
        index[0] = colIdx;
        VARIANT thisCell;
        //thisCell.vt = VT_I8;
        //thisCell.lVal = 8;
        VariantInit(&thisCell);
        hr = SafeArrayGetElement(sa, index, (void*)&thisCell);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout << "NOT OK " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "cell value = " << thisCell.lVal << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

what is the solution for it?
If you have any solution to read data faster from Excel using C++, please welcome..

Comment: Do you need the data to stay within excel?  For example would saving the excel file as a CSV (comma delimited text file) and parsing that be an option?

Comment: Yes, I need the data to stay within excel, so saving into another file type is not my option.

Comment: Your best bet is getting that range function to work. From my experience with excel its slow if you use their build in environment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user3853544.. I got the answer from Microsoft forum.. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/243520e2-26db-4d07-babd-34e7446b340f/reading-excel-data-using-getvalue-in-c?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Post it in the answer box so other people can find it when searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from Microsoft forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/243520e2-26db-4d07-babd-34e7446b340f/reading-excel-data-using-getvalue-in-c?forum=vcgeneral). The code is following:

```
HRESULT hr;
_variant_t tcvt = rngSh->GetValue2();
SAFEARRAY *psa = tcvt.parray;

ULONG cElements = psa->rgsabound->cElements;

LONG lBound, uBound;
hr = SafeArrayGetLBound(psa, 1, &lBound);
hr = SafeArrayGetUBound(psa, 1, &uBound);

for (LONG x = lBound, y = 1; x <= uBound && y <= cElements;)
{
    VARIANT vCell;
    LONG lix[1][2];

    lix[0][0] = x;
    lix[0][1] = y;

    VariantInit(&vCell);
    hr = SafeArrayGetElement(psa, (LONG*) &lix, &vCell);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (vCell.vt == VT_R8)
            wcout << L"Index is " << y << L", " << x << L", Cell Value is " << vCell.dblVal << endl;
        else if (vCell.vt == VT_BSTR)
            wcout << L"Index is " << y << L", " << x << L", Cell Value is " << vCell.bstrVal << endl;
        else
            wcout << L"Index is " << y << L", " << x << L", Cell is not alphanumeric" << endl;
    }

    VariantClear(&vCell);

    x++;
    if (x > uBound && y < cElements )
    {
        x = lBound;
        y++;
    }
}
```